# How to run one function right after another in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, click, settimeout, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm automating a task on Paypal that involves clicking a couple buttons on a page in succession.

Basically, I need to click a radio button and then click a "next" button to advance to the following page. But I can't advance to the next page unless the radio button is clicked first.

I currently have the second function on a timer, but is there a way to start the second function after the first function finishes and the first radio button's pressed?

Here's my code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     PayPal Transfer Radio
// @include  https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/money/balances/withdraw/balance/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
    
$(function(){
  $('[id="BA-SMSNY4E48EHGC__ACH__STANDARD_FUNDSRadioBtn"]').click()
});

setTimeout(function(){
    $('[name="selectFiNext|standard"]').click();
}, 2000);
```

The setTimeout method works, as is, but it's not optimal.

Comment: click on a radio button !? why don't you just set his value ?

Comment: thanks for the response! is that a better option? do you happen to have an example?

Comment: you don't know how to set a radio button value (in JS) ?

Comment: unfortunately, I don't :( I recently start learning JavaScript so I'm spotty with a lot of it. is there an advantage to setting its value as opposed to clicking it?

Comment: `document.getElementById('myForn')['radioGroupName'].value = 'X1'`  where X1 is one of your radio values

Comment: the value for the first radio button is 'BA-SMSNY4E48EHGC__ACH__STANDARD_FUNDS' , am I supposed to change it to something else to get it to automatically be selected?

Comment: we are in the off topic, and this is not the place for a teaching on html / JS programming  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` is the simplest, most reliable method. When patching pages you don't own, it's a great approach.

If you want to click the next button as soon as it appears, decrease the timeout, and if the button doesn't exist yet, set a new timeout. There's also no need to rely on a big dependency like jQuery here:

```
document.querySelector('[id="BA-SMSNY4E48EHGC__ACH__STANDARD_FUNDSRadioBtn"]').click();
const clickNext = () => {
  const btn = document.querySelector('[name="selectFiNext|standard"]');
  if (btn) btn.click();
  else setTimeout(clickNext, 50);
};
setTimeout(clickNext, 50);
```

If you really want to avoid polling, you can also use a MutationObserver on the parent of the button, but that gets significantly more complicated.

If the button appears after a network request, another option that can work is to watch for when network requests complete, with `ajaxComplete` if the site is using jQuery, or by monkeypatching `window.XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: There was a ( character missing right after "querySelector" but everything worked perfectly after that. Thanks, this helps so much.

Comment: Thanks for not using jQuery!

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element. as follows:

```
$(function(){
  $('[id="BA-SMSNY4E48EHGC__ACH__STANDARD_FUNDSRadioBtn"]').click(function(){
    $('[name="selectFiNext|standard"]').click();
  });

  $('[id="BA-SMSNY4E48EHGC__ACH__STANDARD_FUNDSRadioBtn"]').click();
});
```

The following code snippet attaches an event handler *click* to the element with an id of *BA-SMSNY4E48EHGC__ACH__STANDARD_FUNDSRadioBtn* which will trigger the event handle *click* for the element with attribute(s) *name="selectFiNext|standard"*.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've tested the code but it doesn't seem to click the second button. It does click the first radio button, though

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to share a more modern approach that does the same as the accepted answer, but is easier to read in my opinion:

```
// Converts set timeout from callback approach to promise approach
function AsyncTimeout(delay = 0) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay);
    });
}

(async () => {
    // possibly, you might or might not want to awit a bit before you start
    // await AsyncTimeout(100);

    document.querySelector('[id="BA-SMSNY4E48EHGC__ACH__STANDARD_FUNDSRadioBtn"]').click();
    let btn = null;
    // safeguard to prevent endless loop if something goes wrong
    let iterations = 0;
    while (btn == null) {
        await AsyncTimeout(50);
        // try to assign the btn
        btn = document.querySelector('[name="selectFiNext|standard"]');
        // remember the iteration count
        ++iterations;
        // if we tried too many times, just give up
        if (iterations > 100) {
            throw new Error("Couldn't find the button to click");
        }
    }
    btn.click();
})();
```